# vista/win7 magnification API in .NET

Tags: .net, windows, magnification-api

There is magnification.lib in the Win7/Vista SDK for using [Magnification API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692162%28VS.85%29.aspx) for C++. How can I use this API in a .NET windows forms project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28VS.71%29.aspx) for this task. Have a look at the below C# code snippet:

```
[DllImport("Magnification.dll"]
static extern bool MagInitialize();
...
[DllImport("Magnification.dll"]
static extern bool MagUninitialize();

void Main()
{
    if (MagInitialize())
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    ...
    MagUnitialize();
}
```

Here you declare all the methods you need to use in you WinForms app and then you call them just as if they were ordinary methods. You can find many useful information and samples on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) web site. Please also note that you don't need  Magnification.lib at all, it is the library for linking with an unmanaged C/С++ code.