# Issues with Magnification API

Tags: c#, magnification-api

I am having issues with the Magnification API provided my Microsoft.  This is an API that is written in C++ so to use it with C# you must use a series of .dll imports as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276949/vista-win7-magnification-api-in-net).

My issue came after I had the magnification working.  I was using my mouse to magnify a predefined area of the screen, the magnification was set in a rectangle, the rectangle filled a WinForm, I placed the form on top of my mouse (mouse in center of form), and the form would follow my mouse around the screen.

About 80% of the time, the app will launch with a black screen.  I tried many different types of updates but can't find a fix.  The magnification will not show up, it will only show a black screen.  Nothing on the from will show up, only a black screen.  In summary, only a black screen will show up, BECAUSE of the Magnification API.

Comment: Where is the link to the question you mention? The correct approach would be to post *both* this question (as a question) *and* the answer (since you already know it). That is entirely welcome here! But the answer should be posted as an answer, otherwise others can easily miss it.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow.  Though, I should have known better...I will edit the question, with the link. I forgot to paste it in.

Comment: I can't answer my own question for another 7 hours because I have a low reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has to deal with Windows 32 and 64 bit systems.  There's [a Forum post about this problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/fdf965da-4d15-4da6-bf40-4f31168c72bf/).

I changed the Build of my project from x86 to Any CPU  - fixed the problem, no coding needed.

In Visual Studio 2010: In the Solution Explorer right click your project > choose Properties > choose the Build tab > and under Platform Target choose "Any CPU".